# Fetching data for particular Month and year

Tags: c#, ms-access

I tried Query(given below in code) But it is showing me this error

```
No value given for one or more required parameters.
```

but while debugging I am passing date as this

```
string monthYY = dateTimePickerMonth.Value.ToString("M-yy");
```

So what is the right format to check it ,how can I do it ?

**Code for Query**

```
public int GetDrID_MonthWise(string DrName,string monthYY,int refDrID)
        {
            int data = 0;
            try
            {
                string sql = "Select d.DoctorID From Doctor_Master d where d.LastName + ' ' + d.FirstName = '" + DrName + "' AND Patient_registration.RegDate='" + monthYY + "' AND Patient_registration.DoctorID=" + refDrID;
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, acccon);
                rs = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rs.Read())
                {
                    data = Convert.ToInt32(rs[0]);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message.ToString());
            }
            return data;
        }
```

Comment: string sql = "Select d.DoctorID From Doctor_Master d where d.LastName + ' ' + d.FirstName = '" + DrName + "' AND Patient_registration.RegDate='" + monthYY + "' AND Patient_registration.DoctorID=" + refDrID;  check this query  this query is problem particularly check  d.LastName + ' ' + d.FirstName = '" + DrName + "'

Comment: No that is working fine ,problem is with this `string monthYY = dateTimePickerMonth.Value.ToString("M-yy");` and this  part `Patient_registration.RegDate='" + monthYY + "'`

Comment: format(dateTimePickerMonth.Value,"MM-yy")

Answer (score 2):

This piece of your SQL statement informs the db engine `Doctor_Master` is the data source:

```
From Doctor_Master d
```

However, the `WHERE` clause refers to 2 fields which are not present in `Doctor_Master`:

1. `Patient_registration.RegDate`
2. `Patient_registration.DoctorID`

I'm unsure what you actually need.  My hunch is you should `INNER JOIN` those tables.  But I think you should design and test the query in Access, leaving c# out of the picture until after you have the Access query working as you wish.

Comment: `Patient_registration` is my another table shall i write it in from ?

Comment: in database my column is of `dateTime` and I am storing date as `dd-mm-yy` can you just tell me how can I check it with database for particular month and year

Comment: First fix the *"No value given for one or more required parameters"* error.  That is the subject of your question.  If you have another question after you fix that error, you can submit a new question.

Comment: Okay, That ,I got solved ,but in-place of that I got new error

Comment: See whether this question is useful to you: [How to SELECT rows where date field is within a specified year and month?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19416142/77335)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how you are passing your parameters but you need to specify values for all three of your parameters listed

```
public int GetDrID_MonthWise(string DrName,string monthYY,int refDrID)
```